How to determine the text responsible for Google Gemini `block_reason: OTHER`?
I've spent a long time setting up Google Gemini. Now that I've:

Setup a Google Workspace
Connected a GCP Billing Account (If you don't do this, you'll receive Status 429 exceeds quota(?))
Ect.

Anyway, I can now send API requests. These requests contain very large text files. Now I'm getting the error block_reason: OTHER.
I set the safety_settings as shown below, but still receiving the block...
How do I determine what text in this 200-500k token text is the culprit?
Here is the function I'm using:
def start_gemini_chat(api_key, system_message, user_message):
    
    genai.configure(api_key=api_key)

    safety_settings = [ 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}, 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}, 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}, 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}]

    generation_config = {
        "temperature": 0,
        "max_output_tokens": 8192
    }
    
    model = genai.GenerativeModel(
        model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-latest",
        generation_config=generation_config,
        system_instruction=system_message,
        safety_settings=safety_settings
    )

    chat_session = model.start_chat(history=[])

    response = chat_session.send_message(user_message)

    return response.text


how are you uploading the text files

Text, raw ~500k tokens in the user_prompt.

Have you tried uploading them to the file api instead?  Not that loading it raw into the prompt shouldn't work as well.   I have had issues with loading large amounts of text into the prompt but the issue is normally due to strange chars in the text.

Hm...Is there any docs on this or do you recall the types of chars? I'm cleaning newlines, tabs, etc. Would be simple to add them here.

Your request states that it contains large text files and your response error says its was blocked for "OTHER" reasons.
Determining the exact cause and providing assistance without more information is challenging. A straightforward and adaptable solution you can consider is experimenting with various chunks of this massive text file.
Similar to a decision tree, divide your data into chunks to pinpoint the issue.
